# Iphone Rejected Apps

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2, itunes

I update my application from version 1.0 to version 1.1 and I submit my iPhone App to Apple a week ago .Few minutes ago I got this Report from Apple that

> We found that your app uses one or more non-public APIs, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines. The use of non-public APIs is not permissible because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.
>
> We found the following non-public API/s in your app: `setContentToHTMLString`.
>
> If you have defined methods in your source code with the same names as the above-mentioned APIs, we suggest altering your method names so that they no longer collide with Apple's private APIs to avoid your application being flagged in future submissions.
>
> Additionally, one or more of the above-mentioned APIs may reside in a static library included with your application. If you do not have access to the library's source, you may be able to search the compiled binary using "strings" or "otool" command line tools. The "strings" tool can output a list of the methods that the library calls and "otool -ov" will output the Objective-C class structures and their defined methods.
>
> These techniques can help you narrow down where the problematic code resides.

Please tell me, What to do to resolve it?

Comment: Don't use setContentToHTMLString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setContentToHTMLString` is an undocumented method of `UITextView`. You may need to remove it. You are NOT allowed to access the private API.

Comment: unDocumented means what?Actually I have written a string in HTML format.And this string I want to display in UITextview. How to display it then without using this method?  Do you know other way to do this?

Comment: Undocumented means it has no public documentation. It is not a public method. Apple do not want you to use it. You should not use it. You shouldn't have even known that it existed in the first place.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using:

```
setContentToHTMLString
```

Don't use it anymore, if its a private API method and Apple doesn't want you to use it

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a method in the private API, then you will have to find an alternative function. Either from a library or write your own.

If you have written a function named setContentToHTMLString then rename the function (you might like to prefix it- perhaps mySetContentToHTMLString) and change all of the usages over to your new name.

Then you'll be able to resubmit.

Comment: Actually I have written a string in HTML format.And this string I want to display in UITextview. How to display it then without using this method? Do you know other way to do this?

Comment: You should use a UIWebView for displaying HTML. A UITextView is for displaying text.